# Angular2 and Typescript Definitions

Tags: typescript, angular, angular-routing, tsd

I am using the typescript definitions installed with tsd to work with Angular2's preview. Recently they have released 2.0.0-alpha.40 and now my routing doesn't work anymore. I have taken a look at the examples on angular's site and they are referencing for example routerBindings from angular2/router, but the current angular2/router does not define this function. I did ran an update and a reinstall with tsd but nothing changes. How do I know if the angular2 typescript definition published are up to date with the javascript version releases?

Comment: [They stopped using tsd](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/717bd23c37f0c8aa7a30ff221671a09a2629375f/CHANGELOG.md) from alpha-41. `typings: *.d.ts files are now bundled with npm package, tsd link or tsd install no longer needed`.

Comment: As Jesse said, it comes with npm package now https://docs.google.com/document/d/1LvPBh7yxmjr7N1vCQ-kBj4guZGfGLBiz44CfenOX6o0/mobilebasic?pli=1&viewopt=127

Comment: Thanks guys, appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just get the typings via npm install

Put this in your package.json:

```
"angular2": "^2.0.0-alpha.42"
```

Among other things - they have renamed routerBindings to ROUTER_PROVIDERS.

Here is an updated write-up of routing in Angular 2.0: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/routing-in-angular-2.0

You can see working samples here:http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/angular-2.0-examples

Comment: The samples you linked to use `HashLocationStrategy` which is only used to match fragments (ex `/url/path#fragment`).

Answer (score 0):

**This was changed in `angular@2.0.0-alpha.41`**

`routerInjectables` was renamed to `ROUTER_BINDINGS`

`ROUTER_BINDINGS` was then renamed to `ROUTER_PROVIDERS`

**Use `ROUTER_PROVIDERS`**

*It includes:*

- `RouteRegistry` - the registry of defined routes
- `LocationStrategy = PathLocationStragety` - match routes by path

This is basically a shortcut to bootstrap your Router with a default setup.

**For example:**

```
@Component ({
...
})
@View ({
...
})
@RouteConfig ({
...
})
class App {}

bootstrap(App, [ ROUTER_PROVIDERS ]);
```

*Sources:*

- [angular/CHANGELOG.md#alpha41](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-alpha41-2015-10-13)
- [angular/pr#4654](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/4654)